# Golang file reading only reading last line

Tags: csv, go, io, file-read

So I took some publicly available data that looks like this -

this is the file

http://expirebox.com/download/b149b744768fb11aee9c5e26ad409bcc.html

```
,,,% of Total Expenditure,,,
Function Code,Type of Activity,Expenditure,Dollars/Student (ADA),"This District (ADA 49,497)",All Unified School Districts,Statewide Average
1000-1999ÊÊ,INSTRUCTIONÊÊ,"$249,397,226","$5,039",42%,62%,62%
1000,Instruction,"$247,472,790ÊÊ","$5,000",42%,48%,49%
1110,Special Education: Separate Classes,"$1,004,074",$20,N/A,N/A,N/A
1120,Special Education: Resource Specialist Instruction,"$781,629",$16,N/A,N/A,N/A
1130,Special Education: Supplemental Aids & Services in Regular Classrooms,"$46,747",$1,N/A,N/A,N/A
1180,Special Education:  Nonpublic Agencies/Schools (NPA/S),N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
1190,Special Education:  Other Specialized Instructional Services,"$91,985",$2,N/A,N/A,N/A
1100-1199,Instruction - Special Education,"$1,924,436ÊÊ",$39,0%,14%,13%
"Subtotal, INSTRUCTION",,"$249,397,226","$5,039",42%,62%,62%
2000-2999ÊÊ,INSTRUCTION-RELATED SERVICESÊÊ,"$132,783,414","$2,683",22%,12%,12%
2100,Instructional Supervision and Administration,"$89,551,041","$1,809",N/A,N/A,N/A
2110,Instructional Supervision,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
2120,Instructional Research,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
2130,Curriculum Development,"$348,369",$7,N/A,N/A,N/A
2140,In-house Instructional Staff Development,"$19,855",$0,N/A,N/A,N/A
2150,Instructional Administration of Special Projects,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
2100-2199,Instructional Supervision and Administration,"$89,919,265ÊÊ","$1,817",15%,4%,4%
2200,Administrative Unit (AU) of a Multidistrict SELPA,$0,$0,0%,0%,0%
2420,"Instructional Library, Media, and Technology","$8,295,033ÊÊ",$168,1%,1%,1%
2490,Other Instructional Resources,"$538,734",$11,N/A,N/A,N/A
2495,Parent Participation,"$97,830",$2,N/A,N/A,N/A
2490-2495,Other Instructional Resources,"$636,565ÊÊ",$13,0%,1%,0%
2700,School Administration,"$33,932,551ÊÊ",$686,6%,7%,7%
"Subtotal, INSTRUCTION-RELATED SERVICES",,"$132,783,414","$2,683",22%,12%,12%
3000-3999ÊÊ,PUPIL SERVICESÊÊ,"$45,325,938",$916,8%,8%,8%
4000-4999ÊÊ,ANCILLARY SERVICESÊÊ,"$2,207,263",$45,0%,1%,1%
5000-5999ÊÊ,COMMUNITY SERVICESÊÊ,$0,$0,0%,0%,0%
6000-6999ÊÊ,ENTERPRISEÊÊ,"$4,264",$0,0%,0%,0%
7000-7999ÊÊ,GENERAL ADMINISTRATIONÊÊ,"$27,916,858",$564,5%,5%,6%
8000-8999ÊÊ,PLANT SERVICESÊÊ,"$55,172,247","$1,115",9%,11%,10%
9000-9999ÊÊ,OTHER OUTGOÊÊ,"$81,981,716",N/A,14%,2%,2%
"Total Expenditures, All Activities",,"$594,788,926","$12,017",100%,100%,100%
```

It's in a csv.

I have tried this code

```
file, err := os.Open("expenses.csv")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer file.Close()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
}

if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

and  this

```
content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("expenses.csv")

lines := strings.Split(string(content), "\n")

fmt.Println(lines)

check(err)

dat, err := os.Open("expenses.csv")
check(err)

defer dat.Close()

reader := csv.NewReader(dat)
reader.LazyQuotes = true

reader.FieldsPerRecord = -1

rawCSVData, err := reader.ReadAll()

check(err)
fmt.Println(rawCSVData)

for _, each := range rawCSVData {
    fmt.Println(each)
}
```

where check is

```
func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

In both cases I get this result -

```
"Total Expenditures, All Activities",,"$594,788,926","$12,017",100%,100%,100%,1%15%,4%,4%AA,N/A,N/Anified School Districts,Statewide Average
```

Rather than the all the lines.

Why am I only reading the last line?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I suspect your csv file isn't exactly what you think it is. Perhaps the line endings are strange? (Not Windows line endings; that's supported, but something else? Spaces?)

Comment: it's worth a try. You might also look at it in a hex dumper like xxd and make sure it's what you think it is. And of course, make sure you're opening the file you think you are.

Comment: it's uploaded - I'm definitely opening the right file as it's in the same directory as my code, and the last line is being outputted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that this file has `\r` line endings. It also isn't valid UTF-8. Together, those are going to cause `Scanner` a lot of trouble.

First, we can see exactly what's in the file using `xxd`

```
00000000: 2c2c 2c25 206f 6620 546f 7461 6c20 4578  ,,,% of Total Ex
00000010: 7065 6e64 6974 7572 652c 2c2c 0d46 756e  penditure,,,.Fun
```

If you look, you'll see the line ending is `0d`, which is `\r`. `Scanner` needs it to be either `\r\n` or `\n`.

Next, you may run into trouble because it isn't UTF-8. All those `Ê` in there are really `0xCA`, which is not a valid UTF-8 encoding. We can see that in `xxd` again:

```
000000b0: 3939 39ca ca2c 494e 5354 5255 4354 494f  999..,INSTRUCTIO
000000c0: 4eca ca2c 2224 3234 392c 3339 372c 3232  N..,"$249,397,22
```

Go will probably just ship it along as bytes (and get `Ê`), which is what a lot of editors try to do, but it's likely to cause trouble.

If possible, reformat this file to use either Unix or Windows line endings in UTF-8.

Comment: is there a way to programmatically do this?

Comment: Ideally, re-export the file. Otherwise, you could split on `\r` rather than `\n` as a start.

Comment: but I don't have access to each line - I get only the last line when I print out the content

Comment: Because you're splitting on `\n`. This file has `\r` between lines. There are no `\n` in the file, so there's just one line.

Comment: ah you're talking about the first way I was using. Cool. So I assume the second method i was using automatically splits on \n?

Comment: @praks5432, You could stick a simple custom [`transform.Transformer`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/transform/#Transformer) that translates `\r` to `\n` (and perhaps does something with invalid utf8 also) into the path. That will allow you to trivially use a streaming `csv.Reader` on a large file translating as the file is read/streamed. E.g. something like: https://play.golang.org/p/y3kKBI6721.